# How to detect the type of a file in tar.gz

Tags: tar, file-types

I want to detect the type of a file, which is compressed into a tar.gz, but I don't want to extract it.

In a word, is it possible to execute a command (such as `file`) onto a file in a tar.gz without extracting it?

Comment: some sort of fuse filesystem?

Comment: `file -` will read from standard input, if that's good enough & your actual command.

Comment: `file` does not read from stdin. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html

Answer (score 2):

In one word - No. By compressing the input, the result is a complete byte gobbledygook, not interpretable by `file` et al. Even if not compressed, the input files' data - that determine the file type - are stored somewhere in the back of the archive and thus not available for interpretation, even more for multiple files. BTW, extensions do not reliably tell the file type on *nix systems.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tar -tf filename.tar.gz` it will paste you the content of the tar. Then you can check the extension easy.
You can also use `less` and even `vim/nano` to check the contents of tar.